# Drawing slope graph in R using ggplot, Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, aesthetics

I want to create a slope graph in R like this using ggplot
https://rud.is/b/2013/01/11/slopegraphs-in-r/

after cleaning the data and melt the data frame i ran into an error like this: 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (182): x, y, group, colour, label

There's no NAs in my data. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

---

Here's the code

```
#Read file as numeric data
betterlife<-read.csv("betterlife.csv",skip=4,stringsAsFactors = F)
num_data <- data.frame(data.matrix(betterlife))
numeric_columns <- sapply(num_data,function(x){mean(as.numeric(is.na(x)))<0.5})
final_data <- data.frame(num_data[,numeric_columns], 
betterlife[,!numeric_columns])

## rescale selected columns data frame
final_data <- data.frame(lapply(final_data[,c(3,4,5,6,7,10,11)], function(x) scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/100)))

## Add country names as indicator
final_data["INDICATOR"] <- NA 
final_data$INDICATOR <- betterlife$INDICATOR
employment.data <- final_data[5:30,]
indicator <- employment.data$INDICATOR
## Melt data to draw graph
employment.melt <- melt(employment.data)


#plot
sg = ggplot(employment.melt, aes(factor(variable), value, 
                 group = indicator, 
                 colour = indicator, 
                 label = indicator)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=5),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line("black", size = 0.1),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())
sg1
```

This is the data I'm working with

> dput(betterlife)

```
structure(list(X = c("", "ISO3", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "CAN", 
"CHL", "CZE", "DNK", "EST", "FIN", "FRA", "DEU", "GRC", "HUN", 
"ISL", "IRL", "ISR", "ITA", "JPN", "KOR", "LUX", "MEX", "NLD", 
"NZL", "NOR", "POL", "PRT", "SVK", "SVN", "ESP", "SWE", "CHE", 
"TUR", "GBR", "USA", "OECD", "", ""), 
INDICATOR = c("UNIT", "COUNTRY", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", "Czech Republic", 
"Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
"Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", 
"Korea", "Luxembourg", "Mexico", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", 
"Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "United Kingdom", 
"United States", "OECD average", "", "n.a. : not available"), 

Rooms.per.person = c("Average number of rooms shared per person in a dwelling", 
"", "2.4", "1.7", "2.3", "2.5", "1.3", "1.3", "1.9", "1.2", 
"1.9", "1.8", "1.7", "1.2", "1", "1.6", "2.1", "1.1", "1.4", 
"1.8", "1.3", "1.9", "1.566666667", "2", "2.3", "1.9", "1", 
"1.5", "1.1", "1.1", "1.9", "1.8", "1.7", "0.7", "1.8", "1.605208333", 
"1.6", "", ""), 
Dwelling.without.basic.facilities = c("% of people without indoor flushing toilets in their home", 
"", "3.425714286", "1.3", "0.6", "2.722", "9.36", "0.7", 
"0", "12.2", "0.8", "0.8", "1.2", "1.8", "7.1", "0.3", "0.3", 
"2.52", "0.2", "6.4", "7.46", "0.8", "6.6", "0", "2.984285714", 
"0.1", "4.8", "2.4", "1.1", "0.6", "0", "0", "0.1", "17.1", 
"0.5", "0", "2.82", "", ""), 
Household.disposable.income = c("USD (PPPs adjusted)", 
"", "27,039", "27,670", "26,008", "27,015", "8,712", "16,690", 
"22,929", "13,486", "24,246", "27,508", "27,665", "21,499", 
"13,858", "19,621", "24,313", "22,539", "24,383", "23,210", 
"16,254", "19,621", "12,182", "25,977", "18,819", "29,366", 
"13,811", "18,540", "15,490", "19,890", "22,972", "26,543", 
"27,542", "21,030", "27,208", "37,685", "22,284", "", ""), 
Employment.rate = c("% of the working age population (15-64)", 
"", "72.3", "71.73", "62.01", "71.68", "59.32", "65", "73.44", 
"61.02", "68.15", "63.99", "71.1", "59.55", "55.4", "78.17", 
"59.96", "59.21", "56.89", "70.11", "63.31", "65.21", "60.39", 
"74.67", "72.34", "75.31", "59.26", "65.55", "58.76", "66.2", 
"58.55", "72.73", "78.59", "46.29", "69.51", "66.71", "64.52", 
"", ""), 
Long.term.unemployment.rate = c("% of people, aged 15-64, who are not working but have been actively seeking a job for over a year", 
"", "1", "1.13", "4.07", "0.97", "2.98375", "3.19", "1.44", 
"7.84", "2.01", "3.75", "3.4", "5.73", "5.68", "1.35", "6.74", 
"1.85", "4.13", "1.99", "0.01", "1.29", "0.13", "1.24", "0.6", 
"0.34", "2.49", "5.97", "8.56", "3.21", "9.1", "1.42", "1.49", 
"3.11", "2.59", "2.85", "2.74", "", ""), 
Quality.of.support.network = c("% of people who have friends or relatives to rely on in case of need", 
"", "95.4", "94.6", "92.6", "95.3", "85.2", "88.9", "96.8", 
"84.6", "93.4", "93.9", "93.5", "86.1", "88.6", "97.6", "97.3", 
"93", "86", "89.7", "79.8", "95", "87.1", "94.8", "97.1", 
"93.1", "92.2", "83.3", "89.6", "90.7", "94.1", "96.2", "93.2", 
"78.8", "94.9", "92.3", "91.1", "", ""), 
Educational.attainment = c("% of people, aged 15-64, having at least an upper-secondary (high-school) degree", 
"", "69.72", "81.04", "69.58", "87.07", "67.97", "90.9", 
"74.56", "88.48", "81.07", "69.96", "85.33", "61.07", "79.7", 
"64.13", "69.45", "81.23", "53.31", "87", "79.14", "67.94", 
"33.55", "73.29", "72.05", "80.7", "87.15", "28.25", "89.93", 
"82.04", "51.23", "85.04", "86.81", "30.31", "69.63", "88.7", 
"72.95", "", ""), 
Students.reading.skills = c("Average reading performance of students aged 15, according to PISA", 
"", "515", "470", "506", "524", "449", "478", "495", "501", 
"536", "496", "497", "483", "494", "500", "496", "474", "486", 
"520", "539", "472", "425", "508", "521", "503", "500", "489", 
"477", "483", "481", "497", "501", "464", "494", "500", "493", 
"", ""), 
Air.pollution = c("Average concentration of particulate matter (PM10) in cities with population larger than 100 000, measured in micrograms  per cubic meter", 
"", "14.28", "29.03", "21.27", "15", "61.55", "18.5", "16.26", 
"12.62", "14.87", "12.94", "16.21", "32", "15.6", "14.47", 
"12.54", "27.57", "23.33", "27.14", "30.76", "12.63", "32.69", 
"30.76", "11.93", "15.85", "35.07", "21", "13.14", "29.03", 
"27.56", "10.52", "22.36", "37.06", "12.67", "19.4", "21.99", 
"", ""), 
Consultation.on.rule.making = c("Composite index, increasing with the number of key elements of formal consultation processes", 
"", "10.5", "7.13", "4.5", "10.5", "2", "6.75", "7", "3.25", 
"9", "3.5", "4.5", "6.5", "7.88", "5.13", "9", "2.5", "5", 
"7.25", "10.38", "6", "9", "6.13", "10.25", "8.13", "10.75", 
"6.5", "6.63", "10.25", "7.25", "10.88", "8.38", "5.5", "11.5", 
"8.25", "7.28", "", ""), 
Voter.turnout = c("Number of people voting as % of the registered population ", 
"", "95", "82", "91", "60", "88", "64", "87", "62", "74", 
"84", "78", "74", "64", "84", "67", "65", "81", "67", "63", 
"57", "59", "80", "79", "77", "54", "64", "55", "63", "75", 
"82", "48", "84", "61", "90", "72", "", ""), 
Life.expectancy = c("Average number of years a person can expect to live", 
"", "81.5", "80.5", "79.8", "80.7", "77.8", "77.3", "78.8", 
"73.9", "79.9", "81", "80.2", "80", "73.8", "81.3", "79.9", 
"81.1", "81.5", "82.7", "79.9", "80.6", "75.1", "80.2", "80.4", 
"80.6", "75.6", "79.3", "74.8", "78.8", "81.2", "81.2", "82.2", 
"73.6", "79.7", "77.9", "79.2", "", ""), 
Self.reported.health = c("% of people reporting their health to be \"good or very good\"", 
"", "84.9", "69.6", "76.7", "88.1", "56.2", "68.2", "74.3", 
"56.3", "67.7", "72.4", "64.7", "76.4", "55.2", "80.6", "84.4", 
"79.7", "63.4", "32.7", "43.7", "74", "65.5", "80.6", "89.7", 
"80", "57.7", "48.6", "31.1", "58.8", "69.8", "79.1", "80.95", 
"66.8", "76", "88", "69", "", ""), 
Life.Satisfaction = c("Average self-evaluation of life satisfaction, on a scale from 0 to 10", 
"", "7.5", "7.3", "6.9", "7.7", "6.6", "6.2", "7.8", "5.1", 
"7.4", "6.8", "6.7", "5.8", "4.7", "6.9", "7.3", "7.4", "6.4", 
"6.1", "6.1", "7.1", "6.8", "7.5", "7.2", "7.6", "5.8", "4.9", 
"6.1", "6.1", "6.2", "7.5", "7.5", "5.5", "7", "7.2", "6.7", 
"", ""), 
Homicide.rate = c("Average number of reported homicides per 100 000 people", 
"", "1.2", "0.5", "1.8", "1.7", "8.1", "2", "1.4", "6.3", 
"2.5", "1.4", "0.8", "1.1", "1.5", "0", "2", "2.4", "1.2", 
"0.5", "2.3", "1.5", "11.6", "1", "1.3", "0.6", "1.2", "1.2", 
"1.7", "0.5", "0.9", "0.9", "0.7", "2.9", "2.6", "5.2", "2.1", 
"", ""), 
Assault.rate = c("% of people who report having been assaulted in the previous year", 
"", "2.1", "3", "7.3", "1.4", "9.5", "3.5", "3.9", "6.2", 
"2.4", "4.9", "3.6", "3.8", "3.8", "2.7", "2.7", "3.1", "4.7", 
"1.6", "2.1", "4.3", "14.8", "5", "2.3", "3.3", "2.2", "6.2", 
"3.5", "3.9", "4.2", "5.2", "4.2", "6", "1.9", "1.6", "4.1", 
"", "")), 
.Names = c("X", "INDICATOR", "Rooms.per.person", "Dwelling.without.basic.facilities", 
"Household.disposable.income", "Employment.rate", 
"Long.term.unemployment.rate", "Quality.of.support.network", 
"Educational.attainment", "Students.reading.skills", "Air.pollution", 
"Consultation.on.rule.making", "Voter.turnout", "Life.expectancy", 
"Self.reported.health", "Life.Satisfaction", "Homicide.rate", 
"Assault.rate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))
```

[Did I melt the data frame wrongly? since the index of each row are not in the correct order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W3BH.png)

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without a reproducible example.  Instead of showing the `read.csv` line with a reference to a file we can't see, use `dput(betterlife)` to show us the data you are working with.

Comment: @lebelinoz Thanks for commenting, I've added the data to my post, please take a look.

Comment: Hi! Thank you I got it! the problem is that indicator should be written in all caps as in the original column's name